# Difficulty installing Rspec on windows7

Tags: windows-7, ruby, gem

I have ruby 2.2.5p319, Bundler version 1.13.1 and `gem -v` tells me 2.4.5.1

after visiting http://rspec.info/ I made a Gemfile and tried their suggested bundle command:

```
PS C:\Users\user\stuff\Ruby\project> bundle install --binstubs
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.13.1
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed
(https://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs-1.2.5.gem)
An error occurred while installing diff-lcs (1.2.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install diff-lcs -v '1.2.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So, I gave a stab at getting that to succeed:

```
PS C:\Users\user\stuff\Ruby\project> gem install diff-lcs -v '1.2.5'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'diff-lcs' (= 1.2.5), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server ce
rtificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

And at this point I poked around for answers, but am unable to resolve these errors. Of note, I found a tutorial covering windows installation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rspec/rspec_introduction.htm and the recommend the following gem command to install Rspec:

```
PS C:\Users\user\stuff\Ruby\project> gem install rspec
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server ce
rtificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

What do I need to do to get Rspec installed on my HP lappy with windows 7? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, rubygems 2.4 is apparently broken for windows, per http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the procedure outlined here got me a working gem installer: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

...and I'm off and running with the Gemfile bindling.

:)